# JPA: how to map some entities to a different schema of another database instance?

Tags: jpa, orm, schema, cmobilecom-jpa

JPA: is there a way to map some entities to a schema of another database instance? e.g.,

```
@Entity
public class Foo {

}

@Entity
@Table(schema="schema1")
public class Bar {

}
```

The Bar entity is mapped to the schema1 of the same database instance. Is there a  way in JPA to map it to a schema in a remote database instance? It is useful for sharing entities among multiple applications.

Can the "catalog" be used for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by 'remote database'?

If you use `@Table(schema = "myschema", name = "bar")`, Hibernate will qualify all queries with the schema name (e.g. `SELECT e FROM Bar` will ultimately translate to `SELECT * FROM myschema.bar`). If the database user you're using to connect to the DB has access to `myschema.bar` (whatever such a DB object is), then the query will work; if not, then the query will fail.

If you mean 'a remote DB that is a separate server', then, of course, you can only connect to the DB using one JDBC connection per persistence context. If that's your scenario, perhaps you should consult the docs of the RDBMS for ways to connect two DB instances (in Oracle, for example, you could use database links and synonyms).

Make sure that you understand the implications, though, as such a solution introduces its own class of problems (including the fact that you suddenly have implicit distributed transactions in your system).

As a side note, I'm not sure how such an approach is 'useful for sharing entities among multiple applications' or why one would even think 'sharing entities among multiple applications' is somehow useful, but I'd seriously think through the idea of integrating multiple application via shared/linked DBs. It usually introduces more problems than it solves.

Comment: For example, all applications have User entities. User can create single account to access all the apps. So User entities are shared by all the apps, and they can be stored in one schema of a database server.

Comment: I understand the need for applications to share *data*. That does not imply they should share *databases* or *entities*. The problem with shared DBs is that the application data schemas cannot evolve independently. Also, one app updating the data results in inconsistencies in other apps due to cached entities in the persistence context never getting invalidated. You can have a dedicated app that owns the user resource and exposes all operations on it via a well-defined API (e.g. REST), which still makes the data accessible for all other apps, but without the tight coupling shared DBs introduce

Comment: When using a webservice(or LDAP) for user authentication, but there are still associations between User entity and other entities in JPA O/R mappings. User entity needs to be mapped to a table in database for JPA. so this will create duplicated User tables for different apps. Is there a way to avoid this? thanks.

Comment: Well, there can be associations between the user domain object and other domain objects, but they do not have to be expressed as a physical association to an actual `User` entity. You can have just a representation of that domain object (usually, a `userId` property) and the information about the association is still there. And, if you need other user information, you just retrieve it from the source-of-truth user service using the id, whenever needed. No need to keep user data locally (though duplication is not inherently bad, either, it's just another name for caching)

Comment: Understood. but the performance will be slower if fetching user info using webservice every time a list of entities are fetched from database. For example, paginating through Orders with their usernames. How bad is the performance in real application? thanks.

Comment: It might be; it might not, though. Keep in mind that, if the alternative is a database link to a remote database, the request still goes over the network. Also, if you design the data model carefully, you can mitigate the cost. For example, if you need to present the username next to the order in a list, and usernames are unique, just store the `username` (rather than - or besides - `userId`) in the `ORDER` table. And, if you really need more user information every time, use a local cache for users and publish update events from the user service, for other services to synchronize their cache

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well what you mean, you should use two (or more) different persistence context